# why binary file I/O gives some random data on reading

Tags: c++

here Ill clearly explain what i am going to do.

I have a text file which the first 16 bytes contains a thing called a salt and the next 32 bytes contains a thing called iv. (these things are something related to encryption and its not the matter here.)

[image: below is how the text file looks like.]

now I use the below code to read them into two char arrays in order to separate them.

```
   ifstream infile ("salt.txt" , std::ios::binary );


   char* salt = new char[16];
   char* iv = new char[32];

   infile.read(salt , 16 );
   infile.seekg(16, ios::beg);
   infile.read(iv, 32  );

   ui->textEdit_3->append("salt : "+ QString::fromStdString(salt) );
   ui->textEdit_3->append("iv : "+ QString::fromStdString(iv) + "\n\n" );
   infile.close();
```

I use Qt for gui designing and the last three lines are used to display the results on a text edit.

when i read the same text file several times it gives some random data on the last 4 or 5 bytes.

the below image shows some readings took from the same text file.

[image]

whats the matter really going on here. I cant figure out the reason for this strange behavior.

Comment: You call it a text file, but that doesn't look like text, and you're opening the file with `std::ios::binary`. Also, I would look at the data you're reading in the debugger, not in a Qt control. It's possible that your data is correct after you read, but incorrect in the control.

Comment: In fact, the output in your screenshot shows the last few digits of your "vector iv", with additional characters at the end. I think you're missing a null termination.

Comment: I think its because of encoding .. I had experienced same problem when I was dealing with AES encryption .. I solved it by encoding into base64 before writing to file ... Then , when I read ,I again decode it from base64 ..

Comment: I also think that its because of the encoding of the sting. Try to use "QString::formAscii" instead of "QString::formStdString".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QString::fromStdString` takes a `std::string` as a parameter. Since you are passing it a `char *`, it will be implicitly converted to a `std::string` using the `std::string(const char*)` constructor. The problem with that is that it will look for a null character as the string terminator. Which means that if the data you read contains a null character it will terminate early or (most likely what's happening here) it will go past your `salt` buffer until it finds a random null character in memory.

The way to fix it in either case is to force it to explicitly use the `std::string(const char*, size_type)` constructor: `QString::fromStdString(std::string(salt, 16))`

Comment: thanks a lot, I can get the expected output without changing the size of the salt and the vector iv.  well explained.... thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Missing the null character perhaps?

i.e. code should be

```
char* salt = new char[17];
char* iv = new char[33];
iv[32] = salt[16] = 0;
```

Comment: great answer, this gave the expected output. but im not sure will it be able to decrypt the file after increasing the size of the salt and vector iv

Comment: This will still break if the salt or iv happens to contain a null character.